# React + Nodejs : Share code between Front and Back End

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json

I have a front-end built in React and Backend built in Nodejs (framework Adonisjs). I want to share some code between The Client and the Server. My Team can't use NPM or GitHub to do it, because of Company Policies.

Reading NPM docs, I found a possible solution:

On package.json I included the following line in "dependencies" entry:

```
"sharedCodeModule": "index.js:../<sharedCodeFolder>"
```

Doing that, I could import the module in both Front and Backend. The thing is that I've never seen such solution for this problem (not that I searched a lot). Anyone can see any problems in this approach?

Ps: Sorry for bad English. Not a native speaker.

Comment: You can create a private repo on GitHub or BitBucket and use the repo from the URL with proper authentication.

Comment: Due company policies, a can't host the code on github or BitBucket

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question, yet, if your backend is perfectly set to make post and get requests, your front end should only take call your backend funcionalities.
Try to use [npm axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) , and you can have a example.js file like:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
})
```

where you switch that baseURL for what you actually need. And then on your frontend you should have axios post and get requests, for example, you either import the above file in the file of the frontend component and do the post/get like:

```js
import axiosFunc from "./example";

class WhateverComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      (...)
    };
  }
(...)
handleSubmit = async () => {
    const response = await axiosFunc.post("/yourEndPointHere", {
        exampleParam: this.state.param
    });
    message.success("success.");
};
(...)
```

Or, as you can see in the link I gave you, with axios, you make call it directly and do your requests like the example below:

```js
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Again, I'm not sure I understood what you actually want to do, I hope axios helps you.

Comment: Even I found a rare usecase requirement. Incase if I use a bunch of code like data schema validation objects using packages like yup, obviously the validations are pretty much gonna be common to both and require same checks. So I find it difficult to import them in the backend. Its always good to share code which is not so vulnerable or something like that to avoid unnecessary duplication I guess.